# Checking a high exponent congruence without Euler-Fermat?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> In general I'm looking for $a\in \Bbb Z$ such that
>
> $$a^{280}\not\equiv \left(\frac{a}{561}\right)\pmod{561} $$

I want to prove whether $$10^{280}\not\equiv 1\pmod{561} $$
or not.

> BTW: $\left(\frac{a}{561}\right)$ is the Jacobi symbol.

My problem : I know that $$\varphi(561)=2\cdot10\cdot16=320$$
But not sure if I can use this trick in the following way or not:
$$10^{280}=10^{320-40 }$$

Comment: You can use $\text{lcm}(2,10,16)$ in place of $\varphi(561)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Do you mean: $lcm(2,10,16)=2$ so $$10^{2\cdot140}\equiv1^{140}\equiv1$$

Comment: I really don't think that the least common multiple of $2$, $10$ and $16$ is $2$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Sorry, it's 80 ! Well, then : $10^{80\cdot3+40}\equiv(10^{80})^3\cdot10^{40}\equiv10^{40}$

Comment: What does it mean "without Euler–Fermat"? You're using it, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By testing the divisors of $320$ in order, we find rather quickly that the order of $10$ mod $561$ is $16$.

Since $16$ does not divide $280$, we conclude that $10^{280}\not\equiv 1\bmod{561}$.

Comment: @Ihf: Thank you, yeah, I used it, but not in the common way.